# code igniter controller uri segment

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

i'm trying to get the segment depth that triggered the controller inside my controller.

for example:
i have controllers/data/something.php

```
class Something extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $depth = ???;   // should be 2
    }
}
```

would load through www.domain.com/data/something

counting the segments would be irrelevant since i could go to:
www.domain.com/data/something/anotherthing/

and still run the previous controller, but depth should remain 2

any idea how it can be done?

**EDIT**
to clarify:

i want the depth of the part in the uri that triggered the controller (ignoring custom routing).

i don't want all the uri elements, since there could be more elements after the controller/method.

eg. domain.com/controller_name/method_name/param1/param2

only the first 2 parts of the segments triggered the controller

what i have so far is:

```
public function route_segments()
{
    $path = dirname(BASEPATH) . '/'. APPPATH;
    $request = substr(str_replace('\\','/',__FILE__), strlen($path) - strlen(EXT));
    $request = substr($request, strpos($request, '/'));
    $trigger_path = '';
    for ($i=1, $n = $this->uri->total_segments(); $i<=$n && $trigger_path != $request; $i++){
        $trigger_path .= '/'.$this->uri->segment($i);
    }
    $route_segments = explode('/',trim($trigger_path,'/'));
    return count($route_segments);
}
```

problem is i don't want to use __FILE__ since i want it in a parent controller

**SOLUTION:**

added as an answer

Comment: huh? I don't understand, you want all the URI elements (and count them)? There are functions in CI for that.. otherwise I don't know what you mean?

Comment: You could try using CI routes.

Comment: @Jakub i haven't found anything in CI for this

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer.  For more info, read [this post on Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to)

Comment: @galchen - Agreed. If you found a solution, you should post it as a answer and accept it.

Comment: +1. Thanks for posting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i removed it from the post and added it as an answer:

after seeing @Jorge's comment suggesting to use CI routes, i found a simple solution:

```
private function get_route_depth()
{
    $this->load->library('router');
    $route_segments = explode('/',trim($this->router->directory,'/'));
    return count($route_segments);
}
```